# Understanding multiplication using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I am understanding this code for multiplying two numbers using recursion. I dont understand the flow of this. Can someone help me understand, how come it is return product of two numbers without really doing any multiplication. I maybe really poor in recursion, but can someone please suggest good tutorials to practice recursion?

```
static int fun2(int a,int b) {
    int c=0;
    if(b==0)
        return 0;
    if(b%2==0) {
        c=fun2(a+a,b/2);
        System.out.println("even " + c);
        return c;           
    }
    else {
        c=fun2(a+a,b/2)+a;
        System.out.println("odd: " + c);
        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because a * b is imply {a + a + ... + a} b times https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication

Comment: Recursion is the repetitive calling of a function internally in order to create some repeated effect. Due to multiplication being a series of additions, this function adds the `a` parameter a series of  `b` times to simulate the act of multiplying.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplication is ultimately sum of a number specified times, that is what this code is doing.

Below is the call sequence of your recursive method. Lets suppose we called this method with a = 5 and b = 12

```
1 - fun2(5, 12) receives final return of 60 from below call
    2 - fun2(10, 6) receives return from below call 60
        3 - fun2(20, 3) receives return 60; a = 20; fun2 returned 40 from below call thus 40 + 20
            4 - fun2(40, 1) returns 40; a = 20; fun2 returned 0 from below call thus 0 + 40
                5 - fun2(80, 0) returns 0 and recursive loop breaks; a = 80
```

PS: Final method call returns first

I have modified your method a bit, run this, you should get a better picture. Please pass 1 for seq argument.

```
static int fun2(int a,int b, int seq) {
    int c=0;
    if(b==0) {
        System.out.println(seq + " Last Call :: a: " + a + ", b: " + b);
        return 0;
    }
    if(b%2==0) {
        int returned = c = fun2(a+a,b/2, seq+1);
        System.out.println(seq + " EVEN :: a: " + a + ", b: " + b + ", returned " + returned);
        return c;


    }
    else {
        int returned = fun2(a+a,b/2, seq+1);
        System.out.println(seq + " ODD :: a: " + a + ", b: " + b + ", returned " + returned);
        c= returned + a;
        return c;
    }
}
```

To understand recursion, you may find a plenty of recursion examples, pick a few of them. Take a notebook, suppose some input values, keep on drawing each call on paper like a tree. From final call start writing return values in reverse sequence of the call, hopefully you would get a clear picture of how recursion works.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive function have one or more base cases, which identify when to stop recursing, and one or more recursive cases which call the function itself again.

This function has one base case, identified when `b==0` which causes the function to return 0.

The first recursive case is entered if `b%2==0`, meaning if `b` divided by 2 leaves a remainder of 0, i.e. if b is even. In this case the return value is the function itself called with `a+a` and `b/2`.

If b is not 0 (base case), and b is not even (first recursive case), the second recursive case is entered, meaning that b is odd. In this case the return value is the function itself called again with `a+a` and `b/2`, plus `a`. However here remember the arguments are declared as integers so since `b` is odd, `b/2` is really equal to `(b-1)/2`.

Now that we have articulated the cases, we need to explore the algorithm itself. Let's follow an example case through:

```
Call 1: fun2(a=3, b=5)   expecting the answer 15  
b is odd -> recursive case 2, call fun2(3+3, (5-1)/2), and add 3   (*A)

    Call 2: fun2(a=6, b=2)  
    b is even -> recursive case 1, call fun2(6+6, 2/2)   (*B)

        Call 3: fun2(a=12, b=1)  
        b is odd -> recursive case 2, call fun2(12+12, (1-1)/2) and add 12   (*C)

            Call 4: fun2(a=24, b=0)  
            b is zero -> base case, return 0

        c = 0 + 12 = 12   (*C)

    c = 12   (*B)

c = 12 + 3 = 15   (*A)
```

Hope this helps understand the algorithm, as well as understand the concept of recursion as applied to this algorithm.